# what is the best updating method in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to update a row on my table but after updating the row i want to have it so i can return in in the response
i am wondering which is better for performance and best practice
when using sequlize
which is better ?

```
const updatedRows= await Product.update(
{ name, image, price, categoryId },
{ where: { id: prodId } }
);
const updatedProduct = await Product.findByPk(prodId);
```

OR

```
const product = await Product.findByPk(prodId);
product.update( { name, image, price, categoryId });
await product.save()
```

and the updatedProduct here is the product itself

Comment: Show us the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const product = await Product.findByPk(prodId);

if (product) {
await product.update( { name, image, price, categoryId });
} else {
throw new Error('product not found') // res.status(400).send({error: 'product not found'});
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem.